# What does "I have got a witness set up down the road" mean?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

Its from 4th episode of Wandavision.
Actually I wanna know what does set up mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It becomes more clear as the conversation continues:

```
[Jimmy Woo]
I've got a witness set up
down the road in Westview,
and this morning, it
looked like he flew the coop.

[Monica Rambeau]
Your missing person is in the
Witness Protection Program?
```

So Agent Woo has someone in a witness protection program in Westview.  They are someone who is being protected by the the authorities, their identity kept secret.